# Why is my simple angular-phonecat pull request failing?

Tags: angularjs, build, travis-ci

I submitted a PR to angular-compat [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/pull/240), that is simply a few typo amendments (no code changes).

The only thing I can see that might be causing it is the line

```
328    error: pathspec 'step-{0..12}' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Could someone please help me understand why this is failing?

Comment: The current master fails with the same error, so I would guess you didn't break anything, it is/was already broken :)